# Android View reloads every time I change an Element

Tags: android, layout

I am building an App for time management of projects and right now I am stuck at the point that I want to display all collected information for the current project but every time i change one EditView or Button-Text the whole view is reloaded and only the last change is displayed. Unfortunately I have run out of ideas how to describe this problem to find an answere so I am asking here. ;)
My question is: how can I keep the view from reloading every time I change one element because reloading resets all other elements.

View:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/labelJobDatum"
            android:text="Datum:"/>

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnJobDatum"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/labelJobDatum"
            android:onClick="btnDatumClicked"
            android:text=""/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Startzeit:"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnStartZeit"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="btnStartZeitClicked"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Stopzeit:"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnStopZeit"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="btnStopZeitClicked"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pausenzeit:"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnPausenZeit"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="btnPausenZeitClicked"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dauer(tats.):"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDauerTats"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="btnDauerTatsClicked"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dauer(ber.):"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDauerBer"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="btnDauerBerClicked"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Mitarbeiter:"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtMitarbeiter"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Kunde:"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnKunde"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Projekt:"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnProjekt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Projektabschnitt:"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnProjektabschnitt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Aufgabe:"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/txtAufgabe"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/txtAufgabenIDLabel"
                    android:text="Aufgaben ID: "/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtAufgabenID"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtAufgabenIDLabel"
                    android:text=""/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnaufgabenIDNeu"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtAufgabenID"
                    android:onClick="btnNeuAufgabenIDClicked"
                    android:text="neu"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkReisezeit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Reisezeit " />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Beschreibung: "/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtBeschreibung"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkFreigabePV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Freigabe durch PV "/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Rechnungstext:"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtRechnungstext"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Bemerkung:"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtBemerkung"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tätigkeit:"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtTaetigkeit"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnTaetigkeitAbbrechen"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Abbrechen"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnTaetigkeitOk"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnTaetigkeitAbbrechen"
                    android:text="Ok"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

If i for example do a

```
    Button btnDatum = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnJobDatum);
    btnDatum.setText(Datum);
```

only the view is reloaded and only the btnDatum has a text, all other elements are empty.

To illustrate the problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/42L2q.jpg

If I click one of the buttons, they change this buttons text. I want the first button to retain his text after I click the second button, but every time I click one button, this button is the only button to have a text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to close LinearLayout tag at the end of your XML file.
Add `</LinearLayout>` at the end of XML file may help?

Also you didn't set default text for any button `android:text=""` so all button don't have any text on it (empty as you said)

Comment: If you're talking about the first LinearLayout that has all other elements as children: it is correctly endet on the second to last line. Otherwise Eclipse would show an error, wouldn't it?
Yes, there are no default texts because they are to be loaded from a string that gets passed to the activity - the problem being that as soon as I change one text, all other texts are blanked. Is there any other way to set texts?

Comment: You mean all the TextView also blanked? I tested on my AVD and everything fine.

Comment: No, the TextViews keep their text. The problem is that I want to change the EditView for "Mitarbeiter" to a value, then the EditView for "Bemerkung" to a different text. But as soon as I change the text for "Bemerkung", "Mitarbeiter" is reset. How else are EditViews filled with text without having to reload the view?

Comment: Depends on how long you want to persist the data and how big the text is. Checkout this page on Android.com

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: The problem with persistance is that I want to be able to have all the elements show different text at the same time. Right now all text is reset on text change and I can only have one element with text.

Comment: I still don't get it. Please provide with some pictures!